# Locate element without any name or class using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium and I want to grab the 'a' tag so I can navigate into my user profile. What is the best way to do this?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="parent-cont">
  <div class="akd3 dafk4 dfan4">...</div>
  <div class="avndkd dakdf">...</div>
  <div class="fjkad fdadj dfakees">
    <a aria-label="tag" class="oa2 g5iad jhuo" href="/profile.php?id=1792" role="link" tabindex="0">
      <div class="dsks dssks">...</div>
      <div class="dka dk2 fdakdd">...</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[aria-label='tag'][href='/profile.php?id=1792']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='tag' and @href='/profile.php?id=1792']")
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-label='tag'][href='/profile.php?id=1792']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='tag' and @href='/profile.php?id=1792']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code as mentioned:

```
enter code here 
a = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for a in x:
    print(x.get_attribute('arial-label')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).